# Should I focus the cursor to the search field or leave that up to the user?

Tags: search, input-focus

If I show the search field on a user click should I focus the cursor to the search field or leave that up to the user?

I see benefits for both arguments so atm I'm leaving it up to the user. If there is a standard to follow then I'd rather go down that route.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Give the user what they asked for

If the user has to click something to bring up search ... they probably want to search. Focus the field to save them any extraneous clicks, then watch users in action to see what potential pitfalls that creates.